# How to use Reflection in typescript similarly like in java?

Tags: javascript, java, reflection, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using reflection in Java to obtain some information from the TestNG annotation like in the code snippet below:

```java
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("", new MethodAnnotationsScanner())
Set<Method> annotated = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(Test.class)
```

Currently, I have a jest framework with a jest-decorated plugin to help in using annotations.

How I can replicate the same reflection method in Java but in typescript to collect this information from the annotations?

Comment: You want javascript code that gets annotation information from java classes? I don't think thats possible.

Comment: srry typescript

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at Typescript's [Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) + [Reflect Metadata API](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata), which can also be enabled for TS compiler. It doesn't work exactly as Java, but you still can collect required information about annotated entities. Small example of how to collect annotated classes:

```
const myTypes: any[] = []

@annotation
class MyClass {
  type = "report";
  title: string;
 
  constructor(t: string) {
    this.title = t;
  }
}

function annotation(constructor: Function) {
    myTypes.push(constructor)
}

console.log('All annotated classes', myTypes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try my library [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection).
It is pretty advanced Reflection system for TypeScript (*using custom typescript transformer plugin*).

This should be equivalent of your Java code:

```js
import {
    reflect,
    Type
} from "tst-reflect";

// Some decorator...
function test(_, __)
{
}

@reflect()
class A
{
    @test
    foo()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bar()
    {
        return "lorem ipsum";
    }
}

@reflect()
class B
{
    @test
    bar()
    {
        return "lorem ipsum";
    }
}

@reflect()
class C
{
    baz()
    {
        return "lorem ipsum";
    }
}

const decoratedMethods = Type.getTypes()
    .flatMap(type => type.getMethods().map(method => ({ method, type })))
    .filter(entry => entry.method.getDecorators().some(decorator => decorator.name == "test"));

for (let entry of decoratedMethods)
{
    console.log(entry.method.name, "in", entry.type.name);
}
```

**Output**

```
foo in A
bar in B
```

Check [Synopsis](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection#synopsis).
You are able to create instances of those types (even they are from different files) and call those methods.
Also those decorators can have arguments so you will be able to filter methods with same decorators but different arguments.

`tst-reflect` is still in development so the global look ups of types require those `@reflect` decorators or custom decorators with `@reflect` JSDoc tag; reason is size optimization of the generated metadata. But there is an [issue](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection/issues/29) to extend configuration by "include" glob patterns which will include all types from all the modules matched by that globs.

PS: Check out [configuration wiki](https://github.com/Hookyns/ts-reflection/wiki/Configuration) and use this configuration:

> tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // your options...

        // ADD THIS!
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "tst-reflect-transformer"
            }
        ]
    },
    // ADD THIS!
    "reflection": {
        "metadata": {
            "type": "typelib" // this mode will generate and auto-import library with generated reflection metadata
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using reflection can I annotate my interface fields with a decorator? E.g. I have a field1 in my interface IMyInterface. And I want to add @ ApiProperty decorator in the field1 of the the IMyInterface (someting like @ ApiProperty field1: boolean).
Is this possible using reflection?

Comment: @Pradip No, you cannot decorate anything inside interface. It's not allowed by TypeScript. Interfaces do not exist at runtime so you have nothing to decorate.

You have to use eg. abstract class.

Comment: Fair enough. Suppose I implements the interface as a class (class MyClass implements IMyInterface). after that can I able to add @ ApiProperty decorators to each properties of the MyClass?

Comment: Yes.

```typescript
function ApiProperty(targetPrototype: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) { /* Do something,.. or not.. */ }

class MyClass implements IMyInterface {
    @ApiProperty
    myprop: string;
}
```

You have to enable decorators in tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Thanks. My question was:
Can I add this @ ApiPropery decorator in each fields of  MyClass using Typescript reflect. MyClass implements the IMyInterface.

Comment: You mean dynamically?

Decorator is just a function so you can call it manually. `getType<MyClass>().getProperties().forEach(prop => ApiProperty(MyClass.prototype, prop.name))`

But you may need to setup [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata), it depends what are you trying to do and where is the decorator from.